# Windows Task Scheduler running an Excel VBA script

Tags: vba, excel, scheduled-tasks

I have a VBA script in Excel that I wish to run every morning. I want to use the Windows task scheduler to run the VBA script.

I currently use windows task scheduler to run an automated MATLAB process. I have done this by putting the path of the MATLAB exe in the Program/script box and putting other parameters in the Add arguments & Start in text boxes. Is it possible to do something similar with Excel & if so how?

I have seen lots of people mention writing a VBA script which I do not wish to do.

Comment: Using a mini VB Script is the only way I've seen this done.

Comment: think your right. Just created a script